# TSA locks in luggage for travel to Europe

Tags: luggage, airlines, international-travel, tsa

I'll be travelling to Europe from India and have a check-in baggage which has the normal number lock (like a 3-digit password) and also has the TSA lock.
My entry would be in France and would return from Switzerland back to India.

I have never used TSA locks and **DO NOT** plan to use the TSA lock (just the number lock), but my question is does having the unused TSA lock pose any problems while travelling to Europe?
I hope it does not cause any issues.

Comment: I swa the question, but i wanted to ask that i have the TSA built into my luggage with the normal number lock, but would not use the TSA...so does that seem fine?

Comment: As long as it isn't locked, why might it be a problem?

Comment: @testndtv I am not sure I understand what you want to do but the other question really covers all possible scenarios.